# What are the Contraharmonic and Inverse Contraharmonic Means?

Tags: inequality, means

What are the contraharmonic and inverse contraharmonic means? Are there any inequalities that relate them to each other like the AM-GM inequality, for example?

Answer (score 1):

At least, both inequalities are wrong:
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}\cdot\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}\geq\left(\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2...a_n}\right)^2$$ and
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}\cdot\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}\leq\left(\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2...a_n}\right)^2.$$
Indeed, for $n=3$, $a_1=x^3$, $a_2=y^3$ and $a_3=z^3$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives we obtain:
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}\cdot\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}-\left(\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2...a_n}\right)^2=$$
$$=\frac{(x^3+y^3+z^3)x^3y^3z^3}{x^3y^3+x^3z^3+y^3z^3}-x^2y^2z^2=\frac{x^2y^2z^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^4yz-x^3y^3)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}x^3y^3}=$$
$$=\frac{x^2y^2z^2(x^2-yz)(y^2-xz)(z^2-xy)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}x^3y^3}$$ and we see that the last expression can be negative and can be positive.

Comment: This is good Michael, but it's the solutions for the above inequality. This doesn't tell anything about Contra Harmonic and Inverse Contra Harmonic means.  Thank you for the above proof , but was looking for information about the two means.

Comment: @VivekAdi, I know what the contraharmonic mean (CM) is (and hence the inverse CM as well) as I am currently playing around with the concept, but I cannot answer until you add more context to your question once my edit has been approved or rejected. Where did you find out about the CM? Why do you want to find an inequality between the CM and the inverse CM? This type of context could re-open your question again.